# Sort a number by its digits

Tags: python, sorting

I have to sort a vector of integers (all integers have the same length). Integers with the same first digit must be sorted in relation to the second digits, and numbers with the same: first and second digits are sorted by third digit etc. Also, the subsequent digits are sorted alternately (once ascending and once descending)

So when I have `lis = [137, 944, 972, 978, 986]`,
I should get `sorted_lis = [137, 986, 972, 978, 944]`

I know how to sort by selecting digit (a)

```
lis.sort(key=lambda x: int(str(x)[a]))
```

I've tried using insertion sort, (since I have to use a stable sorting algorithm)

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        key = list[i]
        j = i-1
        while j >= 0 and key < list[j]:
            list[j+1] = list[j]
            j -= 1
        list[j+1] = key

    return list
```

Comment: Could you please specify what the problem with your `insertion_sort` is? For example, does it work at all? If it doesn't, is there any error trace that could be helpful?

Comment: Oh, right, my insertion_sort works fine, but I just don't know how to use it it in this task

Comment: Could you share the question you're trying to answer in a more explicit way?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language and I honestly don't know how to explain it in a more explicit way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: multisort with ints

A fun [multisort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) taking advantage of `list.sort` being stable (as explained in that sorting howto section):

```
lis = [137, 944, 972, 978, 986]

pow10 = 1
while pow10 <= lis[0]:
    lis.reverse()
    lis.sort(key=lambda x: x // pow10 % 10)
    pow10 *= 10

print(lis)  # [137, 986, 972, 978, 944]
```

This first sorts by last digit, then by second-to-last, etc, until sorting by first digit. And reverse between the sorts.

#### Solution 2: "negate" every second digit

Another method, turning for example 1234 into 1735 (every second digit gets "negated", i.e., subtracted from 9):

```
def negate_every_second_digit(x):
    result = 0
    pow10 = 1
    while x:
        result = (x % 10 + 1) * pow10 - (result + 1)
        pow10 *= 10
        x //= 10
    return result
lis.sort(key=negate_every_second_digit)
```

#### Solution 3: multisort with characters

Similar to your attempt, but converting to strings only once (at the expense of once converting back to ints at the end):

```
lis[:] = map(str, lis)
for i in reversed(range(len(lis[0]))):
    lis.reverse()
    lis.sort(key=itemgetter(i))
lis[:] = map(int, lis)
```

#### Your solution, completed

Like you said you already know how to sort by a certain digit. You just need to do that for each:

```
digits = len(str(lis[0]))
for a in reversed(range(digits)):
    lis.sort(key=lambda x: int(str(x)[a]),
             reverse=a % 2)
```

#### Benchmark

Benchmark with 100,000 random six-digit numbers:

```
Kelly1  201 ms  192 ms  196 ms
Kelly2  160 ms  154 ms  157 ms
Kelly3  248 ms  237 ms  243 ms
j1_lee  394 ms  396 ms  404 ms
OSA     409 ms  405 ms  419 ms
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTNbtswDL77KQgMRaTMSe0GKIZgOew8bDtstyAw1JhJtNqSZylrgmHPnpGymthpe5gvtmiK/H4oNUe/s2b2oWlPpxI38Bmr6piLSjs5T4Cexj7lGSwgD6unna4wxj4ugNKW2apL5IfW0xZ/Y@tQyEHU2daLRzwuKlU/lAoOczjA7W0sdQN5dsnvYmPqmSXJGdRdDxQHDW6Vx4K7HQuHa2vKotRb7cVBXhC16PaVJ/zZVflnRhdWh8uuwU5xCPjgPeQSxnH7BERM4PBgYx9@P858B8EW/b41sVHyQqk3CcqeKrOeKuzGfEWIa9UI59uUIx22jW1Bg@ZmwZ1StMpsUVRoRGeilPK/fNQe6y16j63QUr7sr42P/ZN38MWWeqOxhIdjBxu8BS5FkCZNpdaYgnLgdwi/9ui8tgaUKaE@Ula157WD0gbaP/OiQrwaBlUREMNyBYXc1QwEnZeTEvSGZLiBO8DKIZSdLil9kDRo9jW2VEOc8ZOIVEnK1Ut3rjsGnj96BEYOFMlTN1RnbeumQt8TYBq4fPv@qU8kFCL92BVu/ezM2UL1ioWx/ZV7r5w3YiQ6Qku1kulgNqNOofBCsULEh2swnO5OSOMxjO9ZGp1ImUWSbFpbg9c1ajK1btjbbpXEFaEtbd3l2YaFZu27f5dhShLDRzPLiizLkrMi90nC1fjzD8Oaw3IVFIlDFN7ub8KhIogUtJldTgbt7BBM1zur1@iifHk2HkcNJ7lMgddR0hQeF6YTHw8Nrvky@GoNnu0YNL/ov7bNEcLlOOXP3gliDvSnE0Z01szDdsGZ1JFm8AHbRT7c45acs5qqpkFTCg5dEmimIzxiyfiG99gZOnc4/@H5H@Yp55DodOAXcVvyBs2m5WnajIIZ06IwqsaimN//HfXnaixGcDOjY@zoDcLT7ZnjTAbtQsUeNylPp38)):

```
def Kelly1(lis):
    pow10 = 1
    while pow10 <= lis[0]:
        lis.reverse()
        lis.sort(key=lambda x: x // pow10 % 10)
        pow10 *= 10

def Kelly2(lis):
    def negate_every_second_digit(x):
        result = 0
        pow10 = 1
        while x:
            result = (x % 10 + 1) * pow10 - (result + 1)
            pow10 *= 10
            x //= 10
        return result
    lis.sort(key=negate_every_second_digit)

def Kelly3(lis):
    lis[:] = map(str, lis)
    for i in reversed(range(len(lis[0]))):
        lis.reverse()
        lis.sort(key=itemgetter(i))
    lis[:] = map(int, lis)

# Modified by Kelly to sort in-place, as the question and my solutions do
def j1_lee(lis):
    def alternate_digits(x):
        return [-d if i % 2 else d for i, d in enumerate(map(int, str(x)))]
    lis.sort(key=alternate_digits)

# The question's attempt, completed by Kelly.
def OSA(lis):
    digits = len(str(lis[0]))
    for a in reversed(range(digits)):
        lis.sort(key=lambda x: int(str(x)[a]),
                 reverse=a % 2)

sorts = Kelly1, Kelly2, Kelly3, j1_lee, OSA

from timeit import timeit
import random
from operator import itemgetter

n = 100_000
digits = 6

times = {sort: [] for sort in sorts}
for _ in range(3):
    lis = random.choices(range(10**(digits-1), 10**digits), k=n)
    expect = None
    for sort in sorts:
        copy = lis.copy()
        time = timeit(lambda: sort(copy), number=1)
        times[sort].append(time)
        if expect is None:
            expect = copy
        else:
            assert copy == expect
for sort in sorts:
    print(f'{sort.__name__:6}',
          *(' %3d ms' % (t * 1e3) for t in times[sort]))
```

Comment: The OP's question contains this intriguing sentence: *"I've tried using insertion sort, (since I have to use a stable sorting algorithm)"*. It's worth pointing out that your answer works specifically because python's `list.sort` is guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: @Stef Done. And added another apparently even faster method.

Comment: @KellyBundy could you explain the first function?

Comment: @OSA__idk It's pretty much the same as what you were apparently attempting, just without strings. Also see the new section "Your solution, completed", where I completed your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a key as follows:

```py
lis = [137, 944, 972, 978, 986]

def alternate_digits(x):
    return [-d if i % 2 else d for i, d in enumerate(map(int, str(x)))]

output = sorted(lis, key=alternate_digits)
print(output) # [137, 986, 972, 978, 944]
```

The key `alternate_digits`, for example, converts `12345` into `[1, -2, 3, -4, 5]`.